# How to get a detailed report of cloned project on Github?

Tags: github, open-source

I am a newbe on Github and I would like to know how I can get a detailed report of clones of my project? For example, amount of clones, country, date of the clone.

On the "Insight > Traffic" it may seems limited.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think that's something you can get.